# C++ Can not initialize with {...}

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11

I am using VS2012, and I wanted to include the following map:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>

std::map<int, int> code_map = {
  {65, 97},
  {66, 98},
  {67, 99},
  {68, 100},
  {69, 101},
  {70, 102},  
};
```

However, the IDE tells me

IntelliSense: Initialization with "{...}" invalid for object of type ""std::map, std::allocator>>""

Does anybody see why this error occurs?
I guess that I am using C++11 if I use VS2012, so I thought that would work.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Are you complaining about C++, or about your IDE? Does it compile?

Comment: Just for reference it works here: http://ideone.com/cykUIc

Comment: I know it is silly, but VS 2012 does not support initializer-lists. Actually, it does not support most of C++11. You need to get VS2013 or upgrade VS2012 compiler.

Answer (score 6):

Visual Studio 2012 doesn't support initializer lists. See this for the C++11 features it does support: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368%28v=vs.120%29.aspx

Comment: Uhm, [according to this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35515) it actually does.

Comment: It's probably better to link to [the 2013 version of the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368%28v=vs.120%29.aspx), which includes the VS2012 status but also shows that one way to solve the problem is to upgrade VS.

Comment: @VladLazarenko That's not the compiler VS2012 comes with.

Comment: @VladLazarenko CTP is a Community Technology Preview. It's more like a beta version of the compiler that you can plug into VS. But yes, intializer lists are supported by the CTP.

Comment: I think it's safe to say we're on the verge of the features being included if they aren't. Whether they're supposed to be there or not, wouldn't it be safer (in some situations at least) to use the old way for just a little while longer?

Comment: The 2012 CTP compiler may support initializer lists, but the accompanying standard library does not. The code in the OP would not compile anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is perfectly fine according to C++11 standard.

I remember reading somewhere that Microsoft C++ compiler haven't implemented uniform initialization and initializer lists [Visual C++ Compiler November 2012 CTP](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35515) release. Perhaps you just need to upgrade your compiler.

Answer (score -1):

There are examples to adding a map here:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/map/

I haven't used maps in c++ myself, but from what others have said, Visual Studio is a little slow at adding that functionality.

This link should help you do it the other way.

Comment: He's using C++11 which allows this syntax.

Comment: Oh. Huh. I'll have to read up on what's new in C++11 more closely.

Comment: good ol' wikipedia. it's a shame it's hidden here - your link is probably the most useful thing on this page outside of the upgrade clarification.